# Proving there exists a set for which a stochastic process is strictly positive

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

I am solving the following:

Let $W_t$ be a one-dimensional brownian motion on $(\Omega,F,P)$.  Prove that for any constants $a,b >0$ there exists $A \in F$ such that $P(A)=1$ and a function $t(\omega)$ such that $inf_{s \ge t(\omega)}(as+bW_{s}(\omega)) \ge 0.$

I honestly have no idea how to approach this problem.  I think I might be able to use the quadratic variation of the process but I'm not sure how.

Comment: One approach would use the fact that $\lim_{s\to\infty}(as+bW_s)/s=a>0$, almost surely.

Comment: @JohnDawkins How do we know this fact?  I am not familiar with it.  From what property of the brownian motion does it follow?

Comment: It's just the Strong Law of Large Numbers in its continuous form: $\lim_{s\to\infty}{W_s\over s}=0$, almost surely.

Comment: @JohnDawkins So the mean of $as+bW_{s}$ is non zero as $s \to \infty$, but how do I define a t(w) and a set A that satisfies the quantity in question?

Comment: Let $A=\{\omega: \lim_{s\to\infty}W_s(\omega)/s=0\}$. Then $P(A)=1$ and if $\omega\in A$ you have $\lim_{s\to\infty}(as+bW_s(\omega))/s=a>0$, so there is
$t(\omega)>0$ such that if $s\ge t(\omega)$ then $as+bW_s(\omega)/s>a/2$. Thus, for $s\ge t(\omega)$, $as+bW_s(\omega)>sa/2\ge t(\omega)a/2>0$.

Comment: hello, did you solve the problem?